# Git repository into a directory in a Git repository

Tags: git, github, symlink

I have found a repository in github that have into the directories other gits repository (as symlink).

But I don't know how make this kind of "symlinks".

[Kivutar/twinsisters/tree/master/libs](https://github.com/Kivutar/twinsisters/tree/master/libs)

Answer (score 6):

They are called **submodules**. See [this chapter in the Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or `man git-submodule` for more information about them.